# Can I declare a variable of a 'protocol' type in an Objective-C interface?

Tags: objective-c

My idea is very similar to declare a variable of an interface type in java.

So for example,

header file 1:

```
@protocol Calculator

@end
```

I then define an `@interface CalculatorImpl` which implements the above `Calculator` protocol.

In header file 2:

```
@interface SomeViewController : UIViewController {


}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtResult;
@property (weak, nonatomic) Calculator* calculator;

@end
```

However, the xcode will flag an error at the calculator line

```
property with 'weak' attribute must be of object type
```

Is this  usage of protocol disallowed by objective-c?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A `@protocol` isn't a type so you can't use it for the type of a `@property`.

What you probably want to do instead is this:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <Calculator> calculator;
```

This declares a property with no restriction on its type, except that it conforms to the `Calculator` protocol.

Comment: How would you create a property with no restriction on it's type in swift, by setting it to type anyobject?

Answer (score 5):

You should use

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <Calculator> calculator;
```

In Objective-C you cannot instantiate a protocol, you can only be conform to it. Thus, instead of having an object of type `Calculator`, you should have a generic object that is conform to `Calculator` protocol.

Otherwise you can use

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) CalculatorImpl* calculator;
```

since `CalculatorImpl` is an interface, not a protocol.