# Why use the <Optional> within a property declaration?

Tags: objective-c, properties

I've encountered the following line in some code that I'm studying:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString <Optional> *name;
```

I don't understand declaring an **optional** attribute. 
I do understand using the '@optional' directive for methods.

BTW: the code is from a library module vs a full app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like it's declaring the property as an NSString that conforms to a protocol named "Optional".
This isn't the same as @optional for methods, or an Optional Type in Swift - it's just the name given to the protocol. Whoever wrote it might want to rename the protocol so it doesn't conflict w/the other uses of the word.

So it's not just a typical NSString, but has additional explicit restrictions that it implements whatever the "Optional" protocol requires.

This way it won't cause problems if you call an "Optional" protocol method on the `name` NSString instance, only to discover that it doesn't know what you're talking about.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9360902/can-i-declare-a-variable-of-a-protocol-type-in-an-objective-c-interface) on the use of Protocols as a Type.

This is also possible in Swift w/o the additional bracket notation - you can just use the name of the [protocol as a Type](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID275).

Comment: True.  I found the following further into the code:

/**
 * Protocol for defining optional properties in a JSON Model class. Use like below to define 
 * model properties that are not required to have values in the JSON input:
 * 
 * @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString&lt;Optional&gt;* propertyName;
 *
 */
\@protocol Optional
\@end